# How to redirect with document ready function in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to redirect after call the DOM.
This is my script.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("<?php echo $url; ?>", function(data, status){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

But I want to do like this.It's not working can anyone help me.
Iupdated my coding.If i use window.location.href='trip_details.php' and alert box its not working.

```
    $username="cde-stng";
    $password="12345666";
    $msg="Welcome To Safetrip Nigeria";

    $url="http://121.241.242.114:8080/bulksms/bulksms?username=".$username."&password=".$password."&type=0&dlr=1&destination=".$mobile."&source=".$mobile."&message=".$msg;



    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("<?php echo $url; ?>", function(data, status){
            //alert(data);
            window.alert('Trip Closed');
            window.location.href='trip_details.php';
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try complete url in window.location.href like http://localhost/trip_details.php

Comment: how are you getting $url in jQuery? check your console what error are you getting?

Comment: You forgot semicolon after alert statement. And check your `$url` variable

Comment: @SanjayChaudhari semicolon is not mandatory in Javascript. But its good habit to use semicolon and may be $url is defined on the same php file.

Comment: Ya i know @RavindraBhalothia, But might be here issue with callback response.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `alert()` between the function.

Remove this line 
`window.alert('Trip Closed')
window.location.href='trip_details.php';`

and then add this

`window.location.href='trip_details.php';`

Comment: Also `trip_details.php` is in the same location ?

Comment: @kailashkumar is there any error ?  add complete URL in `window.location.href='add complete url here';`

Answer (score 0):

What's the use of this $url and $.get here? Please let me know what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

From what I understand, when you load the DOM, you want to show the alert message "Trip Closed", and then redirect to the trip_details.php. If so, there's no need ot this $.get.

You could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Trip Closed");
  window.location.href='trip_details.php';
});
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: here i used SMS API.so i using  $.get("<?php echo $url; ?>";

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code. You should look into the AJAX request. You can try [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to perform a GET request and check what gets returned.

If there is error related to Access Control you can use `dataType: 'jsonp'` to your request. This solved my problem when I was working on Google API.

**Try this to log the data returned from the server in console:**

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "<?php echo $url; ?>",
  dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

**If there are no errors, you can try this:**

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "<?php echo $url; ?>",
  dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(data){
  alert( "Trip Closed" );
  window.location.href='trip_details.php';
});
```

Comment: In this page i send sms..So i used in that script $.get("<?php echo $url; ?>".then i want to show to alert trip closed and redirect.It is possible.

Comment: Yes you can redirect the user after he closes the alert box.

Comment: Can you please add the data you are getting from the ajax request? maybe your Ajax Get request is not getting executed.

Comment: redirct is the problem its not working and not showing the alert

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try adding dataType: 'jsonp' in your request I was facing similar problem with Google API this solved my problem. Also check the developer console for errors.

Comment: it's not working otherwise how can i send sms w/o DOM

Comment: You can perform the GET request using PHP and just JavaScript to redirect the user.